# Help with a proof regarding empty interior

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that every countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has empty interior in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore is included in its own boundary ?

I have no idea how to proceed with this one.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I guess by $R$, you mean the set of all real numbers, it would have been better if you have described the topology.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every set with a nonempty interior contains a nonempty open subset. Every nonempty open set contains an interval with positive radius. Every interval with positive radius...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has nonempty interior. Then it contains an open set, and in particular, it contains an open interval. So can it be countable?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The interior of a set is an open set. What can you say about open subsets of $\mathbb R$?